# Value condition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have number of inputs and I want to set a minimum value of each input section. For example, I have set a minimum input value of `100`. So if the value of any input is less than `100` from all the inputs it will show an error. Otherwise if value of all the inputs is greater than or equal to `100` it will show the success message.

In my case if I enter less than value in an input it will show error but with this less value if I enter greater value in other input it show success message.

```
    <div class="color-quantity not-selected-inputs selected-input-wrap">
        <input type="text" class="custom_small" name="custom_small" onkeydown="return myFunction(event);">
    </div>
    <div class="color-quantity not-selected-inputs selected-input-wrap">
         <input type="text" class="custom_medium" name="custom_medium" onkeydown="return myFunction(event);">
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="custom_large" name="custom_large" onkeydown="return myFunction(event);">
</div>
```

```js
      jQuery('.selected-input-wrap > input').map(function () {
      var total = 0;               
      jQuery('input', this).each(function () {

      total += this.value * 1;
     });

    if (parseInt(total) <= 99) {
        jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>');
    } else if (parseInt(total) >= 100) {
        jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Success</p>'); 
    }
```

Please have a look at the code and help me find out the issue

Comment: Where do you want to verify?

Comment: @dlopez let me try this..

Comment: Also, you're closing a div that you're not opening

Comment: Try with this selector jQuery('.selected-input-wrap>input'). As far as I know, `<div>` tags don't have any value.

Comment: Why are you using `map()` that's used to create an array from a matched set of elements. I think you should look at using `each()` instead. You should also change the selector to `.selected-input-wrap input` and you need to loop through all elements to get the `total` *before* you do anything with the `if` condition.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan yes Brother i have used that please check the question now..

Comment: @Xabby you don't need this `jQuery('input', this).each(function ()`, because in each iteration of the map method `this` will be the `<input>`. In fact, this will fails because you can't find any children `<input>` within a "parent" `<input>` (obviously...)

Comment: @dlopez  So brother you how i can map each input to check if all the inputs has value ==100 and then show the success message otherwise error

Comment: As I said before, remove the last if that you've introduced. Then put `var total` out of the map method. Finally, check the value AFTER the map method.

Comment: I've posted an answer for question. @Xabby, take a look and check if it fits what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110906/discussion-between-xabby-and-dlopez).

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues.

- You should declare `total` outside the loop otherwise you reset it back to `0` on each iteration.
- You should also use a single `each()` call to loop over a set of elements, as `map()` is intended to be used to create an array from those elements.
- You only need to call `parseInt()` once when you add the value to `total`
- Your `else if` condition is redundant and can be replaced by just `else`, or even a ternary as below.

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var total = 0;    
    $('.selected-input-wrap > input').each(function () {          
        total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });

    var msg = total >= 100 ? '<p>Success</p>' : '<p>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>';
    $(".select-quantity").html(msg); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jquery code :-

```
jQuery('.selected-input-wrap > input').map(function () {
      var total = 0;               
      jQuery('input').each(function () {

         total = $(this).val();

         if (parseInt(total) <= 99) {
            jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>');
         }
         else if (parseInt(total) >= 100) {
            jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Success</p>'); 
         }
     });
});
```

It may help you.

Comment: A description of why the OPs original code doesn't work and why this solves the issues is a great help to learners.

Comment: get the value of input tag we have to use .val() instead of value

Answer (score 0):

The **total** variable is looping through all the inputs and only once its returning according to your code. Try closing the each loop after the if-else condition and check once.

```
 jQuery('.selected-input-wrap > input').map(function () {
    var total = 0;               
    jQuery('input', this).each(function () {
      total += this.value * 1;
      if (parseInt(total) <= 99) {
          jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>');
      } else if (parseInt(total) >= 100) {
          jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Success</p>'); 
      }
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var MIN = 100, value = 0;               

jQuery('.selected-input-wrap > input').each(function (idx,el) {
    value += parseInt(el.value);
});

if (value < MIN) {
        jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>');
} else {
    jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Success</p>'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Case i have solved the issue as follows:

```
       var total = 0;
       var array_total = new Array();
       jQuery('.selected-input-wrap > input').each(function(index, value) {
        jQuery( ".right-minimu").remove();
        var total = jQuery(this).val();
        console.log("Total Value  : " + total);
        if (total != '') {

            var t_array = array_total.push(total);
        }
        console.log('Total Array : ' + array_total);

    });

    /******** make array unique *************/

                var unique_total = [];
    jQuery.each(array_total, function(i, el) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(el, unique_total) === -1)
            unique_total.push(el);
    });
        var current_urls = jQuery(location).attr('href');
        var rest = current_urls.substr(37, 9); //
        var current_urls = jQuery(location).attr('href');
        var rest_2 = current_urls.substr(37, 18);
        var rest_3 = current_urls.substr(37, 15);
        var rest_4 = current_urls.substr(37, 8);

    jQuery.each(unique_total, function(key, total) {

        for (var i = 0; i <= unique_total.length; i++) {
         if(rest == "bracelets") {  
            if (parseInt(unique_total[i]) <= 99) {
                jQuery(".select-quantity").css("display", "block");
                jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>');
                jQuery( "#order-overview-table table" ).css("display" , "none") ;
                jQuery( "#order-overview-table").append("<p class='right-minimu'>Please select at least 100 for each color</p>") ;
                jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr("onclick");

                return false;

            } else if (parseInt(unique_total[i]) >= 100) {

                jQuery(".select-quantity").css("display", "none");
                jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('onClick', 'productAddToCartForm.submit(this);');
                jQuery(".select-quantity").html('<p>Products Added</p>').delay(4000);

            }
            }
```